# Curved lines in between vertices

Tags: modifiers

here´s the thing: I´m trying to give a more round like look to my model by modifying the lines in between the vertices, but I don´t know how. Below there´s a picture of what I want (took a snapshot of a video on youtube) I asked the artist how he does that but he doesn´t answer. I tried applying a curve modifier but it gives me a message of error that says "modifier disabled skipping apply". Is that how it´s done? by using the curve modifier? and if it is...how do I enable it?
Thanks in advance, I´d be really grateful for any help you might provide :)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Subdivision Surface modifier
[image]

Make sure the edit cage is turned on
[image]

For more info on the subsurf modifier, here is a link: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf

Comment: Thank you very much! I´ll try it. I really appreciate it :D

Comment: It worked!!! :D :D :D can´t thank you enough. Thank you very very much!!!

Comment: Your welcome:) Clicking the check next to my answer would be appreciated, and be careful on the 'view' and 'render' number. Clicking those up past 4 can be taxing on your computer